# locally noetherian categories and the category of quasi-coherent sheaves over a noetherian scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, modules, injective-modules

It is known that a ring $R$ is noetherian if and only if direct sums of injective $R$-modules 
are injective if and only if every injective $R$-module is a direct sum of indecomposable injective $R$-modules.

1) Is it true that a Grothendieck category $\mathcal{C}$ is locally noetherian if and only if every injective object is a direct sum of indecomposable injective objects?

2) Is it true that a scheme $X$ in algebraic geometry is (locally) noetherian if and only if every injective quasi-coherent sheaf is a direct sum of indecomposable injective quasi-coherent sheaves?

Comment: In algebraic geometry every injective quasi-coherent sheaf over a locally noetherian scheme can be written as a diret sum of some indecomposable injective qc sheves but an example is appeared in Hartshorne (Residues and duality) states that the category of qc sheves over a locally noetherian scheme may not be locally noetherian

Answer (score 3):

According to Exercise 4 in Section 5.8 in *Abelian Categories with Applications to Rings and Modules* by N. Popescu (Academic Press, 1973) the answer to your first question is yes. (I have not checked the details, i.e., solved the exercise.)